# Proper SQL syntax for IF statement when comparing strings and values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a comment and/or rating of a blog post which is stored in SQL Server 2012.

I need to check if the comment is an empty string and if so by pass that code block.

I need to check if the rating is 0.0 and if so bypass that code block.  The comment and rating are injected into the SQL statement using tokens `[Comment]`, `[RatingValue]`.

What is the proper syntax for the above?  Here is what I've tried:

```
IF [Comment] <> ""
    UPDATE EasyDNNNewsComments 
    SET Comment = '[Comment]'
    WHERE CommentID = [CommentID]
ELSE IF [NewRating] <> 0.0
    SELECT 
        EasyDNNNewsComments.Comment, EasyDNNNewsComments.DateAdded, 
        EasyDNNNewsComments.UserID, EasyDNNNewsComments.CommentID, 
        Users.UserName
    FROM 
        EasyDNNNewsComments
    INNER JOIN 
        Users ON EasyDNNNewsComments.UserID = Users.UserID
    WHERE 
        (ArticleID = [ArticleID])
    ORDER BY 
        EasyDNNNewsComments.CommentID DESC

UPDATE ArticleRating
SET RatingValue = [NewRating]
WHERE ArticleID = [ArticleID] AND UserID = [UserID]

UPDATE EasyDNNNews
SET RatingValue = (SELECT Sum(RatingValue) FROM ArticleRating WHERE ArticleID = [ArticleID]) / (SELECT Count(*) FROM ArticleRating WHERE ArticleID = [ArticleID])

SELECT RatingValue 
FROM EasyDNNNews 
WHERE ArticleID = [ArticleID]
```

Comment: IF [Comment] <> "" should be single quotes unless you have `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but this code doesn't make much sence. What is `[Comment]`? is that supposed to be a variable? 
(same goes for `[CommentID]`, `[NewRating]` ect'.

Answer (score 0):

`IF [Comment] <> ""` should be single quotes unless you have `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`

For `UPDATE EasyDNNNewsComments SET Comment = '[Comment]'` I assume you want to set it to the column value, not the string literal thus you would want to remove the quotes around `[Comment]`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer not to "inject" into the code using tags (unless strictly necessary in your situation), but create a procedure and pass parameters.
Follow a raw example (it's possibile there are some errors, as I wrote it without having tables and without doing any test, but it should give you an idea).

Of course, you should add check for errors, check for parameters and other thing to make code stronger and more reliable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DO_IT 
     @pComment VARCHAR(500)
   , @pComment_id INT
   , @pNewRating NUMBER(10,2)
   , @pArticleID INT
   , @pUserID INT)
AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @pComment <> '' 
        UPDATE EasyDNNNewsComments 
        SET Comment = @pComment
        WHERE CommentID = @pComment_id
    ELSE IF @pNewRating <> 0.0
        BEGIN
            SELECT EasyDNNNewsComments.Comment
                , EasyDNNNewsComments.DateAdded
                , EasyDNNNewsComments.UserID
                , EasyDNNNewsComments.CommentID
                , Users.UserName
            FROM EasyDNNNewsComments
            INNER JOIN Users ON EasyDNNNewsComments.UserID = Users.UserID
            WHERE ArticleID = @pArticleID
            ORDER BY EasyDNNNewsComments.CommentID DESC

            UPDATE ArticleRating SET RatingValue = @pNewRating
            WHERE ArticleID = @pArticleID AND UserID = @pUserID;

            UPDATE EasyDNNNews SET RatingValue = 
                               (SELECT Sum(RatingValue) /  Count(*)
                                FROM ArticleRating 
                                WHERE ArticleID = @pArticleID) ;
        END

        SELECT RatingValue 
        FROM EasyDNNNews 
        WHERE ArticleID = @pArticleID;

END
```